# In WebSphere Liberty Profile, can I access variables defined in server.xml programmatically?

Tags: websphere-liberty

I want to access `wlp.password.encryption.key' variable programmatically. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible, but only via an SPI (meaning only in a user or product extension, not in an application).

http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHR6W_9.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.javadoc.liberty.doc/com.ibm.websphere.appserver.spi.kernel.service_1.5-javadoc/com/ibm/wsspi/kernel/service/location/VariableRegistry.html

The VariableRegistry will be a discoverable OSGi Service (choose your favorite discovery mechanism, I recommend DS).

Comment: I'm new to OSGi stuff. Is there a sample program, or pointers to learning materials?

Comment: We have some here: 
https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/#!/SSD28V_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.core.doc/ae/twlp_feat_develop.html
and 
https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/#!/SSD28V_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.core.doc/ae/twlp_bundle_simple_activation.html

and also some blog posts and examples here:
https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/docs/create_your_own_simple_hello_world_user_feature/